# Assign IP range in centOS 7 to network interface

Tags: centos, networkmanager, ip-address

Helllo to all,

I'm very new to server administration, so I have a big question for me.

What is the best way to assign a ip range to the network interface on the server? - I found some examples but I think there should be a better way round. In the most articles they're describing to add a config file for each ip address. I think this is not the best way.
Maybe you have some suggestions.

Examples:
https://www.100tb.com/community/knowledgebase/display/HOW/Adding+Multiple+IP+Addresses+in+CentOS+7

The main ip to access the server is: `123.123.123.38`

I have also the following ip adresses:

```
123.123.123.39
123.123.123.40
123.123.123.41
123.123.123.42
```

What is the best way to add them to the network manager?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, are you trying to allow access to the server from those addresses, or are you trying to assign all of the addresses to an interface on the server?

Comment: I am trying to assign all of the adresses to the network interface of the server. I will edit my post above.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the appropriate interface file, for example `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens192` where `ens192` is the name of the interface you wish to assign the addresses to.

Add `IPADDR1` and `NETMASK1` for the first address, then `IPADDR2` and `NETMASK2` for the second and so on:

```
IPADDR1="123.123.123.39"
NETMASK1="255.x.x.x"
IPADDR2="123.123.123.40"
NETMASK2="255.x.x.x"
```

Then finally, restart `NetworkManager`:

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Comment: The NETMASK can be same for all?

Comment: You'll need to put in the correct subnet mask, I just put `255.x.x.x` as an example. It will most likely be the same subnet mask as whatever is configured for your current address `123.123.123.38`.

Comment: My file is called 'ifcfh-eno1' and inside the file it looks like: TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6_ADDR_GEN_MODE="stable-privacy"
NAME="eno1"
UUID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
DEVICE="eno1"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="XX.XX.XX.XX.138"
PREFIX="29"
GATEWAY="XX.XX.XX.137"
DNS1="1.1.1.1"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_PRIVACY="no"